# How do I scrape specific text from different wikipedia pages with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

For a little personal project, I would like to scrape the episode summary in Wikipedia for TV series:

for example, I started with this page [Andor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andor_(TV_series)).

[image: the summary]

I write this script and it seems to do what I would like:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Specify url of the web page
source = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi_(TV_series)').read()
# Make a soup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(set([text.parent.name for text in soup.find_all(text=True)]))
tab = soup.find("table",{"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable"})
spans =  tab.find_all('td')
# tds with actual text
x = [i for i in range(4,len(spans),5)]
tds = [i for i in spans if spans.index(i) in x]
text = ''
for paragraph in tds:
    text += paragraph.text

#cleaning a bit
import re

text = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]+', '', text)
text = text.replace('\n', '')
text
```

The problem is that this is not working in other cases:
[Big bang theory page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory)
Here, you have to go to main page for the episode list, then there is a page for each season.
Or another different example is:
[Loki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_(TV_series))
Here, the link for the episode summary is in the same page of the main article, but still you have to pass by another page to access the summary.

I would like to know if there is a way to create a script that can take care in a simple way for all these cases. Or there is a simpler way (maybe instead of scraping there is a Wikipedia database that can be access and thus to access the same information).

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to scrape Wikipedia because they already have Client Library;

```
pip install Wikipedia
```

detailed documentation:
https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#api

[image]

Comment: Please look at carefully, for example when you try to get wikipedia.page("Andor (TV series)'") you have the all content, if you want to take links, you can get from ".links" parameter.

Comment: Yes, but that case I have already solved. I am extracting there the text I am interested. The problem arises when I have other cases/ like the Wikipedia page "big bang theory" there you have to go first to the "big bang theory list of episodes" and then to each season individually, then you can extract the text from the table. Then if you check to another series page (example page for 'Loki') you see you need a different process to extract the data (going to another page and extract the data). So it seems you need already three different scripts